# Microphone not woking in Ubuntu 20.10 in browsers but in Audacity and Ardour

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, 20.10, audacity

My microphone is not working in **browsers**, cheese, or any other standard applications but working fine in **Audacity**, **Discord**, **OBS Studio** and **Ardour**. Can someone point out possible problem and solutions and what's the difference between in the recording methods of these applications.

I'm on `64-bit` `Ubuntu 20.10` currently.

`Update`: I found out that I have to use stereo input directly from ALSA to get in the best quality possible. I'm guessing chrome and firefox record only in mono which is causing the problem.
I achieved this successfully in OBS Studio as it was not perfect back then when I posted this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your microphone set?  Go to the settings tab from the menu in the upper right corner.  Then go to Sound, and see that you have an input microphone selected.  Next what browser do you have?  Under settings for your browser, there is often a permission setting.  In firefox it's here https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-manage-your-camera-and-microphone-permissions

Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Yes, I gave the permission already. I tried some things, can you read the update once and give your thoughts. Thanks for replying.